# Find the distribution of people in the store at time $t$, given knowledge of how long they spend there.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes

**Context:** Suppose people enter a grocery store (of infinite size) according to a Poisson process with rate $\lambda$.

**Question:** Fix a time $t > 0$. Find the distribution of the number of people in the store at time $t$.

**Assumptions:**

1) Each person spends a random time in the store given by CDF $F$, such that $F(s)=1$ for some $s < t$

2) The time different people spend in the store are IID random variables.

**My thought process:**

Since people who enter the store before time $t-s$ will not be in the store at time $t$ by condition $(1)$, we look at the interval $(t-s,t]$.

Letting $X_{t}$ be the number of people in the grocery at time $t$, I hope to find $P(X_{t} = k)$ by conditioning on the event that $N(t) - N(t-s) \geq k$ (that is, the number of arrivals in this interval are at least $k$). If we then denote by $t_{i}$ the time the $i$-th person enters the store, then that person will still be in the store at time $t$ if $P(Y_{i} > t - t_{i}) = 1 - F(t-t_{i})$, where $Y_{i}$ is the time the $i$-th person spends in the store. Then conditioning on the event $N(t) - N(t-s) = n \geq k$, we consider all possible combinations of choosing exactly $k$ people to have stayed until time $t$.

**Where this gets me:**

\begin{align*}
P(A_{t} = k) &= \sum_{n=k}^{\infty} P(A_{t} = k | N(t) - N(t-s) = n)P(N(t) - N(t-s) = n) \\
&=  \sum_{n=k}^{\infty} \left( \sum^{{n \choose k}}_{j=1} \prod^{k}_{i \in \mathcal{A}} (1-F(t-s_{i})) \prod^{n-k}_{m \notin \mathcal{A}} F(t-s_{m}) \right) \frac{e^{-\lambda{s}}(\lambda{s})^{k}}{k!}
\end{align*}

where $\mathcal{A}$ is a collection of $k$ people under consideration (it will vary, but I didn't want to introduce even more complicated notation).

**Problems:**

Is there to get at the distribution that is simpler, or is there a way to simplify my calculation? I have a feeling that I might have to use order statistics somewhere here. For instance, I think I may have to use the result that if we condition on an event $N(t)=n$, then the arrival times $(S_{1}, \dots, S_{n}$ are distributed as the order statistics for an IID uniform$[0,t]$ collection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I *think* the below works.  Appreciate any extra eyes when I'm rushing through this.  (There's probably a more intuitive way to arrive at the end result, but I'm too dense to see it.)

Without loss of generality, consider the interval of time from $0$ to $s$, where $s = \min_u \{F(u) = 1\}$.

Let $u \in [0, s]$.  The probability that an arrival occurs in the interval $[u, u+\Delta u]$ is $\lambda \Delta u$, and the probability that this arrival persists to time $s$ is $1-F(s-u)$.  The contribution of this slice of time to the probability-generating function $N_\Delta(z)$ of the number in system at time $s$ is therefore $1-\lambda\Delta u[1-F(s-u)]+\lambda\Delta u[1-F(s-u)]z$, and then

\begin{align}
N_\Delta(z) & = \prod_{k=1}^{s/\Delta u} 1-\lambda\Delta u[1-F(s-k\Delta u)]
                                          +\lambda\Delta u[1-F(s-k\Delta u)]z \\
            & = \prod_{k=1}^{s/\Delta u} 1+\lambda\Delta u[1-F(s-k\Delta u)](z-1)
\end{align}

If we let $N(z) = \lim_{\Delta u \to 0} N_\Delta(z)$, then

\begin{align}
\ln N(z) & = \int_{u=0}^s \lambda(z-1) [1-F(s-u)] \, du \\
         & = \lambda(z-1) \int_{u=0}^s [1-F(s-u)] \, du \\
         & = \lambda(z-1) \overline{u}
\end{align}

where $\overline{u}$ is the mean time in system.  Then

$$
N(z) = e^{\lambda(z-1)\overline{u}}
$$

which means that the number in system at the end is distributed according to a Poisson distribution with mean $\lambda\overline{u}$.

Comment: I'm a little wary, because I did not expect a distribution-free result (the answer depends only on the mean lifetime in system).  But I'm not seeing anything specifically I did wrong yet.

Comment: I corrected my original approach and got something very similar to yours. I'll try to update my post when I get the time.